# PostgreSQL - SequelizeDatabaseError with join table (Code: 42P01)

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to create a join table for many to many relationships.

I am getting the following error:

```
"name": "SequelizeDatabaseError",
"parent": {
    "name": "error",
    "length": 110,
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "code": "42P01",
    "position": "13",
    "file": "parse_relation.c",
    "line": "1160",
    "routine": "parserOpenTable",
    "sql": "INSERT INTO \"user_routes\" (\"id\",\"userId\",\"routeId\",\"createdAt\",\"updatedAt\") VALUES (DEFAULT,'1','1','2017-11-15 03:57:21.791 +00:00','2017-11-15 03:57:21.791 +00:00') RETURNING *;"
},
```

The relationship is between `User` and `Route`:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Route = sequelize.define("Route", {
    open: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: true
    }
  });

  Route.associate = models => {
    Route.belongsToMany(models.User, {
      through: "userRoutes",
      as: "users"
    });
  };
  return Route;
};


module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var User = sequelize.define("User", {
    email: DataTypes.TEXT,
    password: DataTypes.TEXT
  });

  User.associate = models => {
    User.belongsToMany(models.Route, {
      through: "userRoutes",
      as: "routes"
    });
  };

  return User;
};
```

Migration files for user and route does not have much but just the basics. For join table:

```
"use strict";
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable("user_route", {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      userId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
        references: {
          model: "Users",
          key: "id"
        }
      },
      routeId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
        references: {
          model: "Routes",
          key: "id"
        }
      }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable("user_route");
  }
};
```

My controller and route is as following:

```
  create(req, res) {
    return UserRoutes.create({
      userId: req.body.userId,
      routeId: req.body.routeId
    })
      .then(userRoute => res.status(201).send(userRoute))
      .catch(err => res.status(400).send(err));
  },



app.post("/api/userRoutes", userRoutesController.create);
```

So when I try to post to that route, I get the error message on the top of the post.

Comment: I think i kind of figured out the issue. The problem is with the naming convention in sequelize and postgres. Something is not being transfered. It has nothing to do with the many to many relationships. I will update once I resolve the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this same error, and was similarly thrown by an unrelated issue (my SQL clause had single quotes that were all escaped, and, since the query ran when I removed them, I was focused on a way to remove the escaping). My problem was that my migration was generated with a table name that violated the PostgreSQL naming convention; when I corrected this (I had a capitalized first letter in my table name, so I edited the migration for a lowercase first letter and reran it), the error disappeared. Maybe that might fix yours?

Answer (score 2):

After you created db, models and migrations, you need to run

```
sequelize db:migrate
```

before running your application.

If not, it will throw **SequelizeDatabaseError** as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the line:

```
"routine": "parserOpenTable"
```

We will see an error when opening the table.
Most likely, the error is due to the naming of the tables.
Pay attention to capital letters.

Example,
`"./models/user.js"`: tableName *"**u**sers"*, but in DBMS we have table *"**U**sers"*.

**Just change tableName.**