# Writing to localhost Postgres returning infamous"42P01 parse_relation.c" error

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize-cli

**Use-case**: I am trying to write data from a nodejs process running locally (on a docker container) to my locally running postgres server (no docker container). The nodejs process is able to connect to the server (setting the address to `host.docker.internal` solved that problem) however, when I attempt a simple `"SELECT * FROM contact LIMIT 1"` query, this error is returned:

```
{"type":"postgres error","request":"SELECT * FROM contact",
"error":{
"name":"error","length":106,
"severity":"ERROR",
"code":"42P01",
"position":"15",
"file":"parse_relation.c",
"line":"1376",
"routine":"parserOpenTable"}}
```

The relation error suggests the table is not found-- I created this table using a postgres client (postico) and have been able to successfully query the table's contents with other pg clients as well

I see multiple [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47299181/postgresql-sequelizedatabaseerror-with-join-table-code-42p01) are suggesting running the `sequelize db:migrate` command, but would this be the right solution here?

I did not create a model nor a migration, and created the table directly in the table. Is there something else I may be overlooking that is producing this error?

Comment: What do you get if you run that in a SQL client? e.g. `psql`?

Comment: @horse_with_no_name I get back the expected result of the list of records